# dyld:library not loaded:@rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest Reason: image not found

Tags: xctest

I Have Tried some of the solution related to this issues in stack over flow but didn't worked for me 
Help from anyone .

Comment: Please describe what you have tried. Otherwise, we have nothing to go on.

Comment: I have added Earl Grey framework  to the project and just run it show me that error that's it

Comment: Please update your question and add the "earlgrey" tag. All the information people need should be in the question & tags, not here in the comments.

Comment: can any one tell how to use EarlGrey framework for testing App

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a similar problem.This error means your library is Embedded Binaries
Just like this:

1. Find your library in "General->Frameworks,Libraries,and Embedded
   Content"
2. Change "Do NOT Embed" to "Embed&Sign"
3. Rebuild

Everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have to set the "XCTest.framework" status to Optional in Build Phases.